# How do I actually add Filesystem Access API to javascript?

Tags: javascript, filesystems, javascript-api-for-office, filesystem-access, native-file-system-api-js

I've found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API to allow javascript to access the local file system. I feel really dumb, but I can't find anywhere that talks about how to actually add the api. I would really appreciate some help on just getting the first step.

Comment: You don't need to add the API; it's already there, or it isn't. There is a chart on the page with information about browsers and support versions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the API; it's already there, or it isn't. There is a chart on the page with information about browsers and support versions.

I am using this with Chrome. Firefox is supposed to support it but it doesn't have it on my local box... My version may be too old.

Answer (score 1):

You can feature-detect the File System Access API like so:

```js
if ('showOpenFilePicker' in window) {
  // The File System Access API is supported.
}
```

On supporting browsers, this will evaluate to `true`. In order to use the API, see the MDN docs you linked to in your question and/or check out our [article](https://web.dev/file-system-access/).

We maintain a library that uses the API if it is available and that transparently falls back to previous approaches like `<input type="file">` or `<a download>` on non-supporting browsers. You can [read up on ithere](https://web.dev/browser-fs-access/) if you are interested.